# ¿Puede una clase Abstract tener un constructor sin parametros, pero al momento de construir a la clase hija, si tenga parametros?

Tags: java, java-8

Clase padre

```
package Figuras;
public abstract class Figura {

public abstract Figura figura(); //aqui intente pasarle como 
  //que retorne la mism Figura
public abstract double  Area();
}
```

Una de su clases hija

```
public class Triangulo extends Figura {
private int base;
private int altura;
```

> Esto es lo que quiero realizar, un constructor
> pero al momento de yo armar uno en el abstract, no me
> deja realizarlo.

```
public Figura Triangulo(int p_base, int p_altura){
    base = p_base;
    altura = p_altura;
    return null;
}

@Override
public double Area(){
    double resultado = (base * altura)/2;
    return resultado;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se define la clase abstracta `Figura` que contiene el método abstracto `Area`. La clase `Triangulo` extiende a `Figura` y su constructor toma las dimensiones de un triángulo y sobreescribe el método `Area` para calcular el área de una triángulo que por herencia es una `Figura`.

```
    abstract class Figura {
        public abstract double  Area();
    }
    
    public class Triangulo extends Figura {
        private int base;
        private int altura;
        public Triangulo(int p_base, int p_altura){
            base = p_base;
            altura = p_altura;
        }
        
        @Override
        public double Area(){
            double resultado = (base * altura)/2;
            return resultado;
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Figura figura = new Triangulo(2, 4);
            System.out.println(figura.Area());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola bro, pero en si la ayuda es en crear un constructor, ya que el problema es: Una clase abstract que tenga como metodos un constructor y un metodo que devuelva un double, pero en esa clase, no me piden poner atributos, solo en la clase hererdada, y no se puede sobreescribir :(

Comment: Pues solo agrégale el constructor vacío a la clase abstracta y listo. No tienes que sobre escribir el constructor.

Comment: Si bro xd, luego recapacitando, eso hice jajja, gracias igualmente brooo